# Is my device burnt?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I live in Israel,
we have here a 220V network.

I bought for my baby this product from eBay:

[image]

which has these technical data:

[image]

And so, I also bought (from Israel) this adapter:

[image]

the device has 2 functions:

1. chop
2. steam

When I plugged it to the wall , the chopper was working ( the motor was working). ( just tested it for 5 sec)

But when I try the steam  ---- it stopped working  , and also the chop stopped working.

Obviously, something is wrong.

my question:

*( I don't have any other devices which I can test with until the day after tomorrow).*

1) According to what you know + the info I supplied - Is the *device* burnt ? **OR** is the *adapter* burnt ?

Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely the adapter. It's rated for 20 VA, which is about 20 W. The Babycook uses 350 W, that's 20 times as much. Pretty bad for the adapter. If it doesn't have any protection it's probably dead now. It *may* have overload protection, and then it would switch off soon after you switch the Babycook on. In any case it won't work, and I wouldn't try it either. You need a higher power adapter, or rather a 220V/110V transformer. 500 VA is not a luxe.

The adapter is, or was :-( a travel adapter for low-power devices like toothbrushes and shavers.

**More info**
[What is the practical difference between watts and VA (volt-amps)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12831/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-watts-and-va-volt-amps/12834#12834)

Comment: Thank you so very much... , please ... how do you convert VA to W ? ( formula) ....Again , Thank you.

Comment: So most of the chances , is that the Babycook is still working but waiting for the right voltage/Watt ....right?

Comment: @Royi - I added a link about the difference between watts and VA to my answer. I guess the Babycook will still be OK, indeed it just didn't get enough power.

Comment: I posted this comment on another question, so I'll have to for my own answer too :-): I would suggest to wait some time before accepting an answer. Questions with an accepted answer get fewer new answers, which might have been interesting too. You accepted before the US was even awake. Give it a day or so, or at least till you got 3 or 4 answers. You can always change an accepted answer too. Just don't forget to come back! :-)

Comment: Fair enough. and thanks for your honesty and help. i'll come back in 2 days.